# Merge two Pandas data frames on overlapping segments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframes and need to match rows if two columns (with `start` and `end` co-ordinates) are overlapping without crossing boundaries.

For example:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': [0, 10, 23, 35], 'end': [5, 17, 28, 41], 'some_data_1': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'start': [0, 12, 23, 55], 'end': [5, 17, 25, 62], 'some_data_2': ['AA_AA', 'BB_BB', 'CC_CC', 'DD_DD']})
```

Where

```
df_1 :
    start   end some_data_1
        0     5          AA
       10    17          BB
       23    28          CC
       35    41          DD
```

and

```
df_2 :
    start   end some_data_2
        0     5       AA_AA
       12    17       BB_BB
       23    25       CC_CC
       55    62       DD_DD
```

and the desired output is:

```
df_1_2 :
    start_1 end_1   start_2 end_2  some_data_1  some_data_2
          0     5         0     5           AA        AA_AA
         10    17        12    17           BB        BB_BB
         23    28        23    25           CC        CC_CC
         35    41       NaN   NaN           DD          NaN
        NaN   NaN        55    62          NaN        DD_DD
```

Is there an elegant way to check whether one segment (given by `end`-`start`) overlaps with another one and if they do, merge data frame on this condition.

Thanks!

Comment: how did u go about it? reading ur solution would guide respondents

Answer (score 2):

Create a conditional to find if there is an overlap between the two frames, create new columns based on the conditionals, and merge, using how='outer'

What I observed from the data is that if the overlap (end-start) in df_1 is greater than or equal to the overlap in df_2, then add start_data_2, otherwise, leave as is. The calculation hinges on that; if it is a false premise OP, do let me know.

```
#create overlap columns

df_1['overlap']= df_1.end - df_1.start
df_2['overlap']= df_2.end - df_2.start

cond1 = df_1.overlap.ge(df_2.overlap)
df_1['key'] = np.where(cond1, df_2.some_data_2,'n1')
df_2['key'] = np.where(cond1, df_2.some_data_2,'n')

(pd
 .merge(df_1,df_2,
        how='outer',
        on='key',
        suffixes = ('_1','_2'))
 .drop(['key','overlap_1','overlap_2'],
       axis=1)
  )

   start_1  end_1   some_data_1 start_2 end_2   some_data_2
0   0.0     5.0        AA        0.0    5.0      AA_AA
1   10.0    17.0       BB       12.0    17.0     BB_BB
2   23.0    28.0       CC       23.0    25.0     CC_CC
3   35.0    41.0       DD       NaN     NaN      NaN
4   NaN     NaN        NaN      55.0    62.0     DD_DD
```

Comment: The important part is how you created `df_1.overlap`?

Comment: Something tells me that's not the definition of overlap :-)

Comment: oh ok. then i misinterpreted his post. i'll wait for him to comment and if i missed the mark, i'll take it off.

Comment: Well, at second read, that might very well be what OP is asking for. However, merging on the one column data is dangerous because the data can have duplicates.